# AngularJS factory return data is undefined

Tags: angularjs, factory

I'm trying to inject one geoDataFactory into venueDataFactory. When `currentPosition` is logged to the console, the result is undefined whereas assuming successful acquisition of coordinates, currentPosition should be an object containing geolocation data including latitude and longitude. Why is it undefined?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ionic','ngCordova'])
    .factory('geoDataFactory', function($cordovaGeolocation, $location) {
       var currentPosition = {
           'latitude': 0,
           'longitude': 0,
           'altitude': 0,
           'accuracy': 0,
           'altitudeAccuracy': 0,
           'heading': 0,
           'speed': 0,
           'timestamp': 0
       };

       var getCurrentPosition = function() {
           $cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then(function(position) {
               // Position here: position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude
               currentPosition.latitude = position.coords.latitude;
               currentPosition.longitude = position.coords.longitude;
               currentPosition.altitude = position.coords.altitude;
               currentPosition.accuracy = position.coords.accuracy;
               currentPosition.altitudeAccuracy = position.coords.altitudeAccuracy;
               currentPosition.heading = position.coords.heading;
               currentPosition.speed = position.coords.speed;
               currentPosition.timestamp = position.coords.timestamp;
               return currentPosition;
           }, 
           function(err) {
               // error
               console.log("Error with cordova geolocation.currentPosition");
               return err;
           });
       };

       return {
           position: getCurrentPosition()
       }
    })
    .factory('venueDataFactory', function($q, $timeout, geoDataFactory) {
        var currentPosition = geoDataFactory.position;
        console.log(currentPosition);
    })
```

Comment: `getCurrentPosition()` doesn't return anything, so `position` is `undefined`. Should probably return a promise.

Answer (score 1):

I think `position` is being returned before `getCurrentPosition` has returned any data. As Anthony said, you should probably be returning a promise from `getCurrentPosition`. You can do that by adding `return` in front of `$cordovaGeolocation.getCurrentPosition().then...`. That way, `position: getCurrentPosition()` returns the promise.

Then in your `venueDataFactory`, you call that function, and when the promise is resolved, it will return the position and you can assign it to your variable. It would look like this:

```
.factory('venueDataFactory', function($q, $timeout, geoDataFactory) {
    geoDataFactory.position().then(function (response) {
        var currentPosition = response;
        console.log(currentPosition);
    });
})
```